# Is it possible to reuse a popup window in JavaScript after navigating elsewhere in the parent?

Tags: javascript, popup

Suppose we have a website in which you click on a button, and that opens a popup (child) window using JavaScript. So let's call the parent **A** and the popup **P**. In the source of **A**, we'd see something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
P = window.open('P.html', 'P');
</script>
```

So as long as **A** is open, we can interact with **P** in JavaScript using the `P` variable. However, when I click on a link in **A** to go to `B.html`, I lose all the variables. Yet my popup window is still open, so I wonder if there's any way I can link the two back together. Is there any way I can manipulate **P** from within **B**? Thanks much.

Comment: I can think of a few scenarios involving iframes where you're not *actually* changing the page. Additionally you could build an AJAX page.

Comment: No. Child windows are only accessible from the window that opened them. Any other behaviour is a serious security issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I figured out that, to my pleasant surprise, the answer is YES. Mohammad's solution of using `window.top` was not correct; when I try to access `window.top` from within **P**, that just returns a reference to **P** itself. RobG's answer just kind of missed the point.

I found that if I do this periodically from within **P**, everything works:

```
<!-- A.html, B.html -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function setP(ref)
{
    P = ref;
}
</script>

<!-- P.html -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateParent()
{
    if ( typeof window.opener.setP == 'function' ) {
        window.opener.setP(window);
    }
}
window.setInterval(updateParent, 2000);
</script>
```

This way, even when I navigate the parent window from **A** to **B**, **B** will still be updated with a window reference to **P** and once that's established the two windows can then communicate freely with each other again.

Answer (score 1):

A window can access child windows that it opens, and child windows can access their opener window. If either of the windows navigates to a new URI in a different domain, their content is no longer accessible to the other.

e.g.

#### Opener window HTML:

```
<title>Opener window</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

var popWin = (function() {

  var win;

  return {
    open: function() {
      if (!win || win.closed) {
        win = window.open('','child');
        win.document.write(
          '<title>Child window<\/title>' +
          '<script type="text/javascript" src="popWin.js"><\/script>' +
          '<h1>popWin<\/h1>'
        );
      }
      win.document.close();
    },

    close: function() {
      win && win.close();
      win = null;
    }
  };

}());

</script>
<button onclick="popWin.open();">Open child</button>
```

#### popWin.js:

```
window.onload = function() {
   var button = document.createElement('button');
   button.onclick = function() {
     try {
       alert(window.opener.document.title);
     } catch (e) {
       alert('Access to opener failed with error:\n\n' + e.message);
     }
   };
   button.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Check opener'));
   document.body.appendChild(button);
};
```

If you open the opener document, then click on the button a child window is spawned. Clicking on the button in the child window will show the title of the opener document. Navigate the opener to a new domain then click on the button in the child window and you get an access denied error message, something like:

```
Permission denied to access property 'document'
```

Answer (score 0):

if the popup is the top most window you can use `window.top` to access it from within B here is a link with more details [window.top](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_top.asp)

Comment: That doesn't work at all! Although you led me on the right track... maybe you were thinking of `window.opener`?

Comment: `window.opener` will let you access B window object from within P, while `window.top` will let you access P window object from within B. so `window.opener` should work fine.

Comment: That isn't what the OP is asking. The question is if a window can access a document in a child window it didn't open. The answer is **no**. If P was opened by A, then the window with A navigates to page B, then P can no longer access the document in that window.