# How to open different contents in the same pop up window

Tags: javascript, html, href, popupwindow, window.open

What is the best way to display different content in the same pop up window.

I'm doing the following:

```
    <a href = "javascript:openWin('content1.htm')">Content 1</a>
    <a href = "javascript:openWin('content2.htm')">Content 2</a>
    <a href = "javascript:openWin('content3.htm')">Content 3</a>
```

And I have the following javascript:

```
       function openWin(url) {
        window.open(url, "_blank", "toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, top=200, left=300, width=870, height=650");
    }
```

Now, after clicking each link, different pop ups opened. How can I target the same pop up window to display appropriate content, so I have only one pop up opened after clicking second or third link?

Thank you

Comment: Instead of `"_blank"` give it a name e.g. `"ThisSeemsToWork"`.

Comment: You can probably check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003629/is-it-possible-to-reuse-a-popup-window-in-javascript-after-navigating-elsewhere

Comment: and how would I use the name "ThisSeemsToWork" in my code? What will that name reference?

Answer (score 2):

Really easy, you are creating new popup windows because you are specifying `"_blank"` as argument, change it to a name and you'll open in the same window as long it's open.

```
   function openWin(url) {
    window.open(url, "samewindow", "toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, top=200, left=300, width=870, height=650");
}
```

Comment: Yee, I see that I use "_blank", but how can I use "samewindow". Where and how should I specify that that window should be named "samewindow"?

Comment: @RichardN Check if Chrome blocked the popup. This code snipped is standard and will work on all browsers. More information about it: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: Hi Jose. I did research about this. Chrome has changed its functionality around window.open. It ignores all arguments after the url and therefore opens new windows as it ignores the name argument. Please let me know if this snippet works for you in chrome now.

Comment: @RichardN I just tested on chrome and it's working fine. All browsers follows this standard: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#apis-for-creating-and-navigating-browsing-contexts-by-name

Answer (score 0):

A tad late, but I think using the 'location' property will do what you want:

```
var windowName;  // global
function openWin(url) {
   if (windowName) {
      windowName.location = url;
      return;
   }
   else {
      windowName = window.open(url, "window_name", "<feature_list>");
   }
}
```

I was researching this topic because my users want to have an app open on two different windows on different monitors, each window/monitor dedicated to different content within the app itself.  The above code opens up new content in the same window, but there's no "flash" or "pop" that tells the user new content has appeared.  CSS could certainly be used for this, but compare how the above code executes compared to this code:

```
var windowName;  // global
function openWin(url) {
   if (windowName) {
      windowName.close();
   }
   windowName = window.open(url, "window_name", "<feature_list>");
}
```

I think I like the latter UX better.